Draw arrows to connect boxes in shiny dashboard
Im wondering if I could recreate the dendrogram image below by boxes as I do but to connect them with lines like the ones in the image or maybe draw arrows somehow.
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Connected Boxes"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      column(12,
             fluidRow(
               column(2,),
               column(5,),
               column(1,),
               column(4,
                      box(
                        title = "No ADC received",
                        width = 12,
                        height = 80,
                      ))
               
             ),
             fluidRow(
               column(2,),
               column(5,
                      box(
                        title = "Trodelvy",
                        width = 12,
                        height = 80,
                        style = "background-color: red; border-color: #red;",
                      )
               ),
               column(5,)
               
             ),
             fluidRow(
               column(2,),
               column(5,),
               column(1,
               ),
               column(4,
                      box(
                        title = "EV",
                        width = 12,
                        height = 80,
                        style = "background-color: lightblue; border-color: #lightblue;",
                        
                      ))
               
             ),
             fluidRow(
               column(2,
                      box(
                        title = "Bladder",
                        width = 12,
                        height = 80,
                      )
               ),
               column(5,),
               column(5,)
               
             ),
             fluidRow(
               column(2,),
               column(5,),
               column(1,),
               column(4,
                      box(
                        title = "No ADC received",
                        width = 12,
                        height = 80,
                      ))
               
             ),
             fluidRow(
               column(2,),
               column(5,
                      box(
                        title = "EV",
                        width = 12,
                        height = 80,
                        style = "background-color: lightblue; border-color: #lightblue;",
                        
                      )
               ),
               column(5,)
               
             ),
             fluidRow(
               column(2,),
               column(5,),
               column(1,
                      textOutput("arrow2") 
               ),
               column(4,
                      box(
                        title = "Trodelvy",
                        width = 12,
                        height = 80,
                        style = "background-color: red; border-color: #red;",
                      ))
               
             )
      )
    )
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)


